Deserialize JSON with multiple objects
Hi I am trying to consume some data from a api using c# and .Net 8.
I am receiving the data in JSON format however the JSON format does not seem to be correct.
Below is the Sample format of Json format
{   "data": {"object1": {"id": "abcde","name": "xyz","labels": {"app1": "app1", "app2": "app2"},"cid": "1234567890","cn": "cnvalue"}}}
{   "data": {"object1": {"id": "abcde1","name": "xyz1","labels": {"app1": "app11","app2": "app21"},"cid": "1234567890","cn": "cnvalue"}}}

While trying to deserializing the JSON object  I am getting the below error
System.Text.Json.JsonException: ''{' is invalid after a single JSON value. Expected end of data. Path: $ | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 0.'
Any help will be appreciated.
Please do let us know if you need any additional information.

That's not valid json. It's probably "jsonlines". Parse line by line.

It is the JSON lines format, which means multiple JSONs separated by newlines. Each JSON is formatted on a single line. You need to split the input on lines and parse each line as an individual JSON.

There's no "JSON Lines" format, that's an attempt by someone to hijack the decade(s)-old practice of streaming JSON by storing one unindented JSON object per line by imitating Douglas Crockford's original JSON site. It's neither a standard nor is it related in any way to JSON.org. You'll find the exact same thing called ND-JSON, JSON-Lines etc. The only true standard is json-seq which doesn't use newlines to separate records

in .NET 9 [tag:jsonlines] format is supported, see parsing text that is a sequence of JSON objects without enclosing brackets (there is no root object) in .NET?.  Before .NET 9 see this answer by Nathan.
